# Quick question about Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose I have a function $f,$ and after computing its Fourier transform using $\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$ (which is the definition for $L^1$ functions), I show that $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Does it automatically mean $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})?$

I was thinking it should, since the Fourier transform definition for $L^1$ and $L^2$ coincides for functions in the intersection, and the Fourier transform defines a bijection on these two spaces.

Comment: $f \in L^2$ iff $\hat{f} \in L^2$. Furthermore, you're implicitly assuming that $f \in L^1$ because you're using the integral definition of $\hat{f}$. This is true regardless of $\hat{f} \in L^1$, although the latter condition allows you to say more about $f$, e.g. it implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Regarding your last paragraph, the Fourier transform is a bijection on $L^2$, but not on $L^1$. The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function need not be $L^1$ in general.

Comment: I see, I have forgotten that the FT is not a bijection in $L^1$. Thank you.